# How can I average grouped values in pandas while ignoring those that satisfy a test?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I want to apply groupby().mean() to but need to apply a test and ignore those values which meet it.

As in the table below I want to group by area then average the results.
However, I want to ignore pairs of 0 that occur in columns with the first n characters in the column name in common.

I feel that it should be possible to do this with regex and iteration but I can't see it.

```
area    art   ark   bag  bar

area1   4     8     2    7
area1   0     0     6    3
area2   4     4     4    1
area2   6     2     0    0
area3   6     1     1    8
area3   7     0     0    3
```

In the above table for (n=2) the area1 and and area2 0 pairs should be ignored because (art & ark) and (bag & bar) meet the column name test.

However the area3 pair should not be ignored as (ark & bag) do not share (n=2) initial characters.

The output I'm looking for is as below

```
area      ark         art         bag        bar

area1      4           8        (2+6/2)     (7+3/2)
area2   (4+6/2)     (4+2/2)        4          1
area3   (6+7/2)     (1+0/2)     (1+0/2)     (8+3/2)
```

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

edit: Both tests only need to consider neighbouring columns sorted alphabetically (assume thie dataframe is already in this format)

Comment: `df.replace(0, pd.np.nan).groupby('area').mean()` ?

Comment: your problem sounds a little generic. As stated, do we need to search over all couple of columns for matching names?

Comment: No. Apologies Quang. That was vague. Only neighboring columns when sorted alphabetically (already taken care of).

Comment: BallpointBen. That would remove all zeros from the calculation regardless of whether they meet the test or not.